# How to open created WorkBook with C# using memory, without saving it?

Tags: c#, excel, memorystream, closedxml

I'm creating an Excel file using ClosedXML and i would want to open the created workbook without saving it to the server. So is there a chance to open ClosedXML created WorkBook without saving it anywhere ? my guess would be using memory, but how do u do it ?

```
wb.SaveAs(filePath);      
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
```

im now opening it while saving it, but since few people could be using the program and trying to get the excel file at the same time it would lead to error. So is there a way to open the WorkBook file created with ClosedXML without saving it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the WorkBook to a MemoryStream.

```
wb.SaveAs(new MemoryStream());
```

But then you need some program to watch the *file* (bytes)

To avoid getting an exception when an other user tries to access the file you should write a method to wait for the file to get released.

Suggestion: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/164428/C-FileStream-Lock-How-to-wait-for-a-file-to-get-re

Comment: For your answer i would need to have the file saved already and i want to open the workbook without it beening actually saved

Comment: Sadly i don't know a excel program where you can send the bytes of the file and it will open it. The only solution i know at the moment is to save the file - check before if it already exists, when yes save it with an other name - and open it. When done delete the file. Or you add an excel viewer in your application

Answer (score 0):

If your primary problem is that "few people could be using the program and trying to get the excel file at the same time it would lead to error" then you can simply generate unique file name each time (for example using GUIDs).

ClosedXML does support saving file in a memory stream, but Excel will not accept this as a valid data source.